# Gpresults html report shows setting as enabled as well as disabled?

Tags: group-policy

I am little confused on why my gpresults html reports shows both enabled and disabled (or vice versa) for settings. In this example screenshot, is this policy really enabled or disabled?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, this was a stupid question. The second part at the bottom just shows that the sub setting within the policy is disabled while the main policy itself is enabled.

[Looking at the policy using GPO editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G86kb.png)